# Will rotated images affect the validation accuracy of an algorithm during testing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

i wanted to know if i rotate an image and then test it with a CNN algorithm, will this affect the accuracy for validating the image?

Before proceeding with my assignment, i wanted some guidelines.
Thank you in advance

Comment: From MNSIT dataset and accuracy people achieved with that dataset vs others datasets proves manipulating images do give a positive boom to the accuracy of the model. I would recommend reading this article to go in-depth to see why it happens?https://d4nst.github.io/2017/01/12/image-orientation/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much the rotation is.

Consider for example the MNIST dataset. If some of your numbers are slightly rotated, it may be possible for the network to learn to differentiate the numbers.

But if the numbers are rotated a lot, your accuracy will also reduce significantly.

In that case, you will need to adjust for the rotation when training your network.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the problem is, if its image classification, rotating images, can be a good data augmentation step, but it depends what kind of rotation is it, if its rotation at 90 degrees, then that might not be so good. if its angled a bit then thats good but normally rotation does one of two things, it either adds black corners to the images or it crops a certain part of it, black edges aren't a very good idea, cropping is better but only if it doesn't crop the object in the image.

Comment: i got this issue when I capture image from my mobile phone and fed it for testing in the model. I was very confused about the wrong accuracy that i got. Later I found that images captured from Samsung phone are in a landscape position which always rotate the image. I was not able to find a proper solution for that, so i trained my model with rotated images also.